# What is wrong with the mutableList size with Firebase references

Tags: android, firebase, for-loop, kotlin

I wanted to turn a huge code block(it is a part of it, in fact there are four choiceRefs)

```
    val mChoice1Ref = instance.getReference("/course/tests/" + mQuestionNumber + "/" + mChoiceNumber)

    mChoice1Ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val choice = p0.getValue().toString()
            buttonChoice1.text = choice
        }
    })

    val mChoice2Ref = instance.getReference("/course/tests/" + mQuestionNumber + "/" + mChoiceNumber)

    mChoice2Ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
            val choice = p0.getValue().toString()
            buttonChoice2.text = choice
        }
    })
```

to something like that

```
    val choiceList = mutableListOf<String>()

    for (mChoiceNumber in 1..4) {
        val mChoiceRef = instance.getReference("/course/tests/" + mQuestionNumber + "/" + mChoiceNumber)

        mChoiceRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                choiceList.add(p0.getValue().toString())
            }
        })
    }

    buttonChoice1.text = choiceList[0]
    buttonChoice2.text = choiceList[1]
    buttonChoice3.text = choiceList[2]
    buttonChoice4.text = choiceList[3]
```

but all I get is `Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0` exception on the very first line of setting text to a button. What is wrong?

Comment: `addValueEventListener` is an asynchronous function.

Comment: First check the choice list size then use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ValueEventListener` doesn't run immediately. `addValueEventListener` adds the listener to get invoked when the request has finished, so it adds and exits. You never know when the request is finished or failed.

Hence for loop exits before the values are actually added to the list. And even the request to be done in the order it is started is not necessary to be finished in the same order.

You can integrate a [Channel](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-channel/index.html) in your code and send Pair of id to choiceText in order to receive and correctly assign the text to their respective fields.

```kotlin
val scope = viewModelOwner.viewModelScope
val channel = Channel<Pair<Int, String>>()
for (mChoiceNumber in 1..4) {
    instance
        .getReference("/course/tests/" + mQuestionNumber + "/" + mChoiceNumber)
        .addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) { }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                // launch coroutine into any scope
                scope.launch{
                    channel.send(mChoiceNumber to p0.getValue().toString())
                }
            }
        })
}

// probably launch the coroutine into viewModelScope
scope.launch {
    repeat(4) {
        val (id, choiceText) = channel.receive()
        when(id) {
            1 -> buttonChoice1.text = choiceText
            2 -> buttonChoice2.text = choiceText
            3 -> buttonChoice3.text = choiceText
            4 -> buttonChoice4.text = choiceText
        }
    }
}
```